# Basic real analysis proof.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: M \to N$ be continuous in the sense of the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. Prove that if $\{p_n \}$ is a convergent sequence in $M$ with limit $p$, then $\{f(p_n) \}$ is a convergent sequence in $N$ with limit $f(p)$.

Note: This is now a homework question; I'm missing this proof either because I missed class or lost notes.

Thank you.

Comment: You had better do some search for "sequential convergence".

Comment: @user72625 Do you know how to accept answers? You have asked 22 questions so for but haven't accepted a single answer. No one would like to help you  if you are this much irresponsive.

Answer (score 3):

All that we have to show is that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $N$ such that  $|f(p_n)-f(p)|< \epsilon$ for all $n > N$.

Since $f$ is continuous at $p$ we have that given $\epsilon >0$ there exist $\delta >0$ such that

$|f(x)-f(p)|< \epsilon$ for all $x$ such that $|x- p|< \delta$.... $(1)$

Also since $p_n$ is sequence converging to $p$ then we know that given $\delta > 0$ there exist $N$ such that

$|p_n - p|<\delta$ for all $n> N$. ....$(2)$

combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we see that given $\epsilon > 0$ we can find $N$ such that  $|f(p_n)-f(p)|< \epsilon$ for all $n >N$. Hence sequence $f(p_n)$ converges to $f(p)$.

Comment: You used absolute value signs.  But user7* did not say that $M$ and $N$ are subsets of the real line.

Comment: Wouldn't be real analysis then though

Comment: @GEdgar I have assumed that they are subset of the real line. If user will response then slight modification will do the job. Unfortunately, user only ask question with no response.